# Font size in PDF export with legended plots not working

Tags: bugs, export, legending, pdf-format, fonts

I need to export plots as PDF with a given image and font size. Everything is working fine if there is no legend for that plot. However, if I want to export legended plots, the font size is decreased in the exported PDF. Here is a small working example:

```
plotWithoutLegend = 
 ListPlot[Table[f, {f, {Sin[x], Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}], 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> "Frame label font size is 12", 
  ImageSize -> 200, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}];
Export["plotWithoutLegend.pdf", plotWithoutLegend]
```

This yields the expected font size. However, when trying to export:

```
plotWithLegend = 
 ListPlot[Table[f, {f, {Sin[x], Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}], 
  Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {"sin(x)", "cos(x)"}, 
  FrameLabel -> "Frame label font size is about 8 pt", 
  ImageSize -> 200, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}];
Export["plotWithLegend.pdf", plotWithLegend]
```

the font size of the frame label is about 8 pt. This can be seen by importing the PDFs in a LaTeX document or by verifying the font size with Acrobat Pro.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround for this behavior?

Comment: I suspect this may have to do with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091553/font-sizes-print-smaller-than-indicated , even Mr.Wizard's proposed solution doesn't immediately fix it in this case.  To be precise, the font size in the second case is 8.64 pt (according to Acrobat).  However, if you export to PNG, the pixel size of fonts seems identical.

Comment: Speculating on the reason for the difference:  if you plot without a legend, the output is a Graphics object.  If you plot with a legend, it's more akin to a `Row` (i.e. a formatted notebook expression)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that the exported `PDF` file doesn't contain the correct bounding box information appropriate for the image size that you specified. Maybe an acceptable work-around is to specify this information by hand as follows:

```
fixSize[plt_, width_, height_] := Graphics[
  {
   Inset[plt]
   },
  ImageSize -> {width, height},
  AspectRatio -> Full
  ]

g1 = fixSize[plotWithLegend, 260, 150]
```

[image: g1]

```
g2=fixSize[plotWithoutLegend,260,150]
```

[image: g2]

By wrapping both plots as `Inset`s in another `Graphics` with the same fixed dimensions in both cases, the output of `Export` is guaranteed to have the same size, measured in pixels.

This is where the manual adjustment is required: Here I chose the dimensions `260`$\times$`150` such that the legend fits into the given bounding box. That is why the pictures now look shifted horizontally with respect to each other: they are centered in the same amount of space, and the one without legend uses less room.

It's easy to modify this so that the plots are both left-aligned (e.g.), by using the additional arguments of `Inset`. Just replace it by `Inset[plt, {Left, Bottom}, {Left, Bottom}]`

In the exported `PDF` file, all the fonts will have their expected size in points.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. However, tuning the dimensions of the bounding box manually is quite cumbersome...